# Using ExternalInterface with Flash on wordpress?

Tags: actionscript-3, wordpress

I don't see anyway to specify "javascript" file on a new wordpress page added. Then how can i use it with my flash file. The flash app doesnot run without externalinterface.

Comment: So what's your question?

Comment: How to use ExternalInterface with Flash on Wordpress ?